# How can I disable requiring a verification code when making purchases with Family Sharing enabled?

Tags: family-sharing

My wife and I have Family Sharing setup. I am the organizer, and she is set as a Parent/Guardian. Over the last month or so, whenever she buys an app in the App Store on her iPad, it prompts for her password, and then also a verification code that is sent to my devices.

This is very annoying for her, and I have no problem with her making purchases without me verifying them, so we would like to turn this feature off so she can buy anything on the App Store without getting a code for me. However we don't see any setting that would control this - all we can see is an option for approving purchases made by children in our family (we don't have kids so this feature is turned off).

Does anyone know how to disable requiring a verification code when making purchases on the App Store?